# Построение предложения с деепричастным оборотом

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли построено предложение с деепричастным оборотом. Деепричастие в прошедшем времени, а основной глагол в настоящем. Разве так можно?

Предложение: *Договорившись о нашей встрече с ней, еду в село и обдумываю предстоящую с ней беседу.*

Comment: А правда, в чем сомнения? Не вижу ни малейшего повода сомневаться в грамматической корректности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно, а почему же нет?!

*Сначала* он (или она; примем условно, что он) договаривается, а *потом* едет. Возможно, он описывает это уже впоследствии. Но описывать так какую-то последовательность событий нормально. В данном предложении выбран тот момент времени, когда он *отправляется в село и уже успел договориться о встрече.*

Answer (score 4):

Можно и с глаголом в будущем. *Завтра, договорившись с утра на работе, я после обеда на пару часов уйду в ломбард.* Деепричастие совершенного вида во временном отношении выражает предшествование действию глагола, а не прошедшее время.

Answer (score 3):

@Верьясова, я не очень в курсе современных методических веяний, но деепричастия все-таки делят не по времени, а по виду - совершенного и несовершенного вида. Поэтому никаких ограничений на использования их с глаголами любого времени не существует. Вид деепричастия означает завершенность (формальную, грамматическую) действия, деепричастием обозначенного, к моменту действия основного, т.е. сказуемого. А это возможно и в будущем, и в прошлом - во всех сочетаниях.

Вот с глаголами - да, обычно в однородных (только в однородных!) членах не рекомендуется смешивать временные формы, но и это не императив, а скорее рекомендация для научного и делового стиля.